# Form not submitting when pressing enter key?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Form won't submit when pressing enter? It should work because other forums suggest that it should work without any config? Don't want to add any extra javascript.
I'm on bootstrap

I tested for syntax errors and other stack overflow question's but none solved my problem

```html
<h1>Signup</h1>
<form method="post" action="/signup">
  <label for="username">username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<br>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <label for="username">username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Might other code not included here be interfering?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1>Signup</h1>
<form method="post" action="/signup">
  <label for="username">username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <label for="username">username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be inside an input field of the form then press enter to submit